# Variance of sum of $2n$ random variables.

Tags: statistics, random-variables, covariance, variance

Let $X_1,X_2....X_{2n}$ be random variables such that $V(X_i)=4;(i=1,2...2n)$ and $Cov(X_i,X_j) =3, (1 \leq i\ne j\leq2n)$ . Then

$V(X_1-X_2+X_3-X4......+X_{2n-1}-X_{2n})$

I am not able to figure out the covariance terms. 
According to formula sum of dependent positive random variables we have 
$\begin{align}\operatorname{Var}\left(\sum_{i=1}^nX_i\right) &= \sum_{i=1}^n\operatorname{Var}(X_i)+{2\sum_{i<j }} \operatorname{Cov(X_i,X_j)}\end{align} \\$

In my case if we take odd terms and even terms together  they will give us positive co variance consecutive terms gives negative covariance. I am confused how to merge my result or is there standard result for alternating signs ?

$V(X_1-X_2+X_3-X4......+X_{2n-1}-X_{2n})=8n-()$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Var}{\operatorname{Var}}\newcommand{\Cov}{\operatorname{Cov}}$You want to find:
\begin{align}
\Var\left(\sum_{k=1}^{2n}(-1)^{k-1}X_k\right)
\end{align}
By setting $Y_k=(-1)^{k-1}X_k$ we get according to your formula:
\begin{align}
\Var\left(\sum_{k=1}^{2n}(-1)^{k-1}X_k\right)=\sum_{k=1}^{2n}\Var((-1)^{k-1}X_k)+2\sum_{i<j}\Cov((-1)^{i-1}X_i,(-1)^{j-1}X_j)
\end{align}
We have $\Var(aX)=a^2\Var(X)$ for constant $a$. Now figure out what is $\Cov(aX,bY)$ in terms of $\Cov(X,Y)$. Can you do that?

---

**Edit.** Avoiding a large amount of comments.
One has $$\sum_{i<j}\Cov((-1)^{i-1}X_i,(-1)^{j-1}X_j)=3\sum_{j=1}^{2n}(-1)^j\sum_{i=1}^{j-1}(-1)^i$$
Moreover $\sum_{i=1}^N(-1)^i=\frac{1}{2}((-1)^N-1)$ so:
$$\sum_{j=1}^{2n}(-1)^j\sum_{i=1}^{j-1}(-1)^i=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{j=1}^{2n}((-1)^{2j-1}-(-1)^j)=-n-\frac{1}{4}((-1)^{2n}-1)=-n$$
putting everything together:
\begin{align}
\Var\left(\sum_{k=1}^{2n}(-1)^{k-1}X_k\right)=8n+2\cdot 3\cdot (-n)=2n
\end{align}

Comment: $2\sum_{i<j}(-1)^{i+j}  $Cov$ (X_i,X_j)$?
$(i+j=2n)$ it  wll be overall positive?

Comment: @Damn1o1 Yep! That is it!

Comment: So that will give me $8n-6n=2n$. Thanks you ve been very helpful. I am learning these things.

Comment: @Damn1o1 I'm not sure about the positivity. Be careful with $\sum_{i<j}$ it means:
$$\sum_{i<j}=\sum_{i<j\leq 2n} = \sum_{j=1}^{2n}\sum_{i=1}^{j-1}$$ hence $$\sum_{j=1}^{2n} (-1)^{j}\sum_{i=1}^{j-1}(-1)^i\Cov(X_i,X_j)=3\sum_{j=1}^{2n}(-1)^j\sum_{i=1}^{j-1}(-1)^i$$ now figure out what $\sum_{i=1}^{j-1}(-1)^i$ is.

Comment: Moreover let $b_j:=\sum_{i=1}^{j-1}(-1)^i$. Then we have $b_1=0$ , $b_2=-1$ , $b_3=0$, $b_4=-1$ etc etc. So you can easily find a closed form for $b_j$.

Comment: Just tell me what will be the answer.

Comment: @Damn1o1 I edited the post to include everything. Coincidence: the same answer you had assuming that the contribution of the covariance was somehow  positive. I don't understand what you did, but here is the solution. Have a nice day.

Comment: I have one more question could you help me with that not related to this one .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72433/discussion-between-shashi-and-damn1o1).